# HSV image thresholding result is not the same with ImageJ and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, imagej, threshold

My problem is that I would like to threshold an **HSV** image, thanks to `OpenCV` `inRange` function.
To find my range of hue, I use `ImageJ`.
I uploaded my picture after I changed it from **RGB** to **HSV**, and threshold it manually.
My **HSV** image, converted from **RGB** image is:

[image: im1]

I obtained these values from `imageJ`:

> H (62;100) S (0;255) V (0;255)

And this threshold result:

[image: res]

But when I try to obtain the same result with a Python script using `OpenCV`, I obtain this:

[image: res2]

Here is my script:

```py
import cv2

image_color = cv2.imread(image_color)
image_hsv_convert = cv2.cvtColor(image_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.imwrite(folder_dest, image_hsv_convert)

H_low = (62/255)*180
H_high = (100/255)*180
HUE_MIN = (H_low,0,0)
HUE_MAX = (H_high,255,255)

frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(image_hsv_convert, HUE_MIN, HUE_MAX)
cv2.imwrite(folder_dest2, frame_threshed)
```

I know the H values in `OpenCV` go from *"0 to 179"*, so I've converted `ImageJ` values into `OpenCV` values. What's the problem here ? Is `ImageJ` showing me a wrong result ? Or is my code wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In ImageJ, HSV (threshold tool) values all range from 0 to 255. But In OpenCV, S and V range from 0 to 255, while H only ranges from 0 to 180. In ImageMagick, S and V range from 0 to 255, but H ranges from 0 to 360. In GIMP, S and V range from 0 to 100 and H ranges from 0 to 360. So one must understand which range is being used by each tool for HSV.

Thus different scaling of the ranges, especially, for H in different tools account for different threshold results.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV `imwrite()` function can only write BRG images. When you pass a matrix with an image saved in HSV format, it interprets the HSV image as a BGR image. If you convert the HSV matrices to BGR and then write the BGR ones this should work.

eg

```
frame_threshed_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(frame_threshed, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv2.imrwite(folder_dest2,frame_threshed_bgr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't really understand your eg. Do you suggest me to convert my BGR image into HSV, then to turn it back to BGR, and then to do the threshold ? Or do I convert the result of my threshold (without imwrite()-ing it) into BGR then imwrite() it ? For this last example, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm suggesting that whenever you use imwrite you ensure that the image you're writing is in BGR format, as it needs to be in that format to be correctly written. What does your output look like when you do this?

Comment: I have an OpenCV error when I try to cv2.imwrite(folder_dest2,frame_threshed_bgr). I think it's due to the fact that I try to convert to BGR a binary image, which is the result of the inRange().

Comment: Ah how silly of me, I assumed inRange() returned an HSV image. That will be the issue. You will need to do additional processing based on the matrix frame_threshed to obtain your answer

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained my purpose wrong. What I want to obtain is a binary image, the resulf of the threshold of the HSV image. But what I'm expecting to see in my binary image as white shapes is what you can see in black in the threshold I did on ImageJ.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what ImageJ is doing, but opencv is simply returning a matrix consisting entirely of 0s and 255 based on whether a pixel falls in or out of the specified range. In areas which are within the given range you will get white(255), in areas outside the range black(0). If you want something similar to ImageJ you will need to do additional processing.